# How to store the collected Field from the table into a variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to collect the username Field from the database table and store it in a variable, so that i can compare it with the $_POST['user'] which i collected from the form. if the username from the form matches the database, login is successful.

```
<?php
$userField = $_POST['user'];

 $sqlHost   = 'localhost';
 $sqlDb     = 'DBNAME';     //Database Name
 $sqlId     = 'USERNAME';       //Database User Name
 $sqlPass   = 'PASSWORD';       //Database Password
 $link = mysqli_connect($sqlHost,$sqlId,$sqlPass,$sqlDb);
 mysqli_select_db($link,$sqlDb);

//Read table records
 $conn = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table_name where username='$userField');

if ('username'== '$userField')
{
echo Login Successful
}
else
{
echo Login Unsuccessful
}
 //Close MySql Connection
 mysqli_close($link);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: What error you are getting..please post

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in  on line 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this really is your code, then you need to do a lot.
Add quotes, semicolons and SQL-injection checks...

```
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table_name where username='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $userField) . "'");
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if ($fetch['username']== $userField)
{
    echo 'Login Successful';
} else {
    echo 'Login Unsuccessful';
}
```

This should work a little bit more...

Answer (score 1):

```
if ('username'== trim($userField))
{
echo 'Login Successful';
}
else
{
echo 'Login Unsuccessful';
}
```

add semicolon at end of line

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?php
$userField = $_POST['user'];

 $sqlHost   = 'localhost';
 $sqlDb     = 'DBNAME';     //Database Name
 $sqlId     = 'USERNAME';       //Database User Name
 $sqlPass   = 'PASSWORD';       //Database Password
 $link = mysqli_connect($sqlHost,$sqlId,$sqlPass,$sqlDb);
 mysqli_select_db($link,$sqlDb);

//Read table records
$conn = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table_name where username='".$userField."'");
$res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn);
$username=$res['username'];
if ($username== $tocompare)
{
echo "Login Successful";
 }
else
{
echo "Login Unsuccessful";
}
 //Close MySql Connection
 mysqli_close($link);
exit();
?>
```